# Iphone configurable button menu

Tags: iphone, button, menu, customization

Im just wondering if anyone knows the best approach to make a configuable button menu. Im trying to make one like the standard iphone button interface where I will 4 buttons across and 4 buttons down. And like on the iphone button menus, when you press and hold it allows the users to move the buttons around to the configuration they desire. Also like the facebook iphone app menu.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably the [Three20 Library](http://three20.info/).  It has lots of general functions, but specifically you would use TTLauncherView, which is derived from the Facebook application.  There is an example included in library source, which can be downloaded [Here](http://github.com/facebook/three20).

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't use the Three20 library is to use paging with the UIScrollView.